# Dynamically generating a Navbar with a headless CMS in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to dynamically generate parts of my navbar. I'm using GraphQL and Sanity.IO (headless CMS) and I was able to query and generate my pages. I have a query for the slug as well but I'm just not sure how I go about implementing that into my Navbar. Any help would be appreciated. I tried passing them as props to every page through pageProps but I'm a bit stuck on what to do next or if there's another approach/method to this. Thanks!

App.tsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Layout from "../components/layouts/Layout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const sanityNav = pageProps.navigationTree;
  return (
    <Layout navigation={sanityNav}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Navbar

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { MenuIcon, XIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

import Menulink from "./Menulink";

import { Navigation } from "../../utils/data/Navigation";
import { navigationTree } from "../../utils/data/Navigation";

type NavBarProps = {
  navigation: Navigation
}

function Navbar({ navigation }: NavBarProps) {
  return (
    <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-white shadow-lg fixed w-full top-0 z-50">
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className="mx-auto ">
            <div className="relative flex items-center justify-center h-16 w-full ">
              {/* Mobile menu button*/}
              <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center lg:hidden  justify-self-start">
                <Disclosure.Button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-blue-750 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
                  <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  ) : (
                    <MenuIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>

              {/* Main */}
              <div className=" flex items-center justify-evenly flex-grow w-full">
                {/* Logo */}
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <Image
                    src="/images/navBar/coolGymLogo.jpeg"
                    alt="A picture of the Cool Gym Logo"
                    layout="fixed"
                    width={100}
                    height={60}
                    quality={100}
                  />
                </div>
                {/* Menu Items */}
                <div className="hidden lg:flex flex-grow justify-center">
                  <div className="flex space-x-4">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <div key={item.id} className="flex">
                        {!item.dropdownOptions ? (
                          <Link href={item.href} className="">
                            <a className="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium hover:text-blue-750">
                              {item.name}
                            </a>
                          </Link>
                        ) : (
                          <Menu as="div" className=" relative">
                            <Menu.Button className="relative flex px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium hover:text-blue-750">
                              {item.name}
                              <ChevronDownIcon
                                className="block h-6 w-6 ml-2 text-accent"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              />
                            </Menu.Button>
                            <Transition
                              as={Fragment}
                              enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                              enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                              enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                              leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                              leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                              leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                            >
                              <Menu.Items className="origin-top-right absolute left-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                                {item.dropdownOptions.map((option, index) => (
                                  <Menu.Item key={index}>
                                    {({ active }) => (
                                      <Menulink
                                        href={option.href}
                                        className={`${
                                          active && "bg-slate-100"
                                        } block px-4 py-2 text-base text-gray-700'`}
                                      >
                                        {option.name}
                                      </Menulink>
                                    )}
                                  </Menu.Item>
                                ))}
                              </Menu.Items>
                            </Transition>
                          </Menu>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Transition
            enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          >
            <Disclosure.Panel className="lg:hidden relative">
              <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 absolute bg-blue-750 w-full">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <div key={item.id}>
                    {!item.dropdownOptions ? (
                      <Disclosure.Button
                        key={item.name}
                        className="text-white hover:bg-slate-700 hover:text-white block px-3 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                      >
                        <Link href={item.href}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Disclosure.Button>
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        <Disclosure.Button
                          key={item.name}
                          className="text-white hover:bg-slate-700 hover:text-white block px-3 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </Disclosure.Button>

                        {item.dropdownOptions.map((option, index) => (
                          <Disclosure.Button
                            key={index}
                            className="block ml-4 px-3 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-slate-700 hover:text-white"
                          >
                            <Link href={option.href}>{option.name}</Link>
                          </Disclosure.Button>
                        ))}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </Disclosure.Panel>
          </Transition>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Navigation.ts

```
  id: number;
  name: string;
  href: string;
  current: boolean;
  dropdownOptions?: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    href: string;
  }[];
}[];

export const navigationTree: Navigation = [
  { id: 1, name: "Home", href: "/", current: true },
  { id: 2, name: "About", href: "/about", current: false },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Facilities",
    href: "/",
    current: false,
    dropdownOptions: [
      { id: 2, name: "Cardio Room", href: "/facilities/cardio-room" },
      { id: 3, name: "Weight Room", href: "/facilities/weight-room" },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Straps Balls and More",
        href: "/facilities/straps-balls-and-more",
      },
      { id: 5, name: "On The Wall", href: "/facilities/on-the-wall" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Classes",
    href: "/",
    current: false,
    dropdownOptions: [
      { id: 2, name: "Yoga", href: "/classes/yoga" },
      { id: 3, name: "Body Sculpting", href: "/classes/body-sculpting" },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Functional Fitness",
        href: "/classes/functional-fitness",
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Strength and Balance ",
        href: "/classes/strength-and-balance",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Trainers",
    href: "/",
    current: false,
    dropdownOptions: [
      { id: 2, name: "Sandy Dixon", href: "/trainers/sandy-dixon" },
      { id: 3, name: "Justin Chinevere", href: "/trainers/justin-chinevere" },
    ],
  },
  { id: 6, name: "Membership", href: "/membership", current: false },
  { id: 7, name: "Schedule", href: "/schedule", current: false },
  { id: 8, name: "CBD", href: "/beyond-cool-cbd", current: false },
  { id: 9, name: "Contact", href: "/contact", current: false },
];
```

[Trainers] page

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";

import client from "../../apollo-client";

import {
  AllTrainersDocument,
  AllTrainersQuery,
  TrainerBySlugDocument,
  TrainerBySlugQuery,
  TrainerFragment,
  SlugTrainerFragment,
} from "../../generated/graphql";

import { navigationTree, Navigation } from "../../utils/data/Navigation";

type TrainerProps = {
  name: string | null | undefined;
  bio: string | null | undefined;
  bio2: string | null | undefined;
  bio3: string | null | undefined;
  url: string | null | undefined;
  navigationTree: Navigation;
};

export default function Trainer({ name, bio, bio2, bio3, url }: TrainerProps) {
  if (url === null || url === undefined) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col bg-slate-150">
        <Head>
          <title>{name} | Cool Gym Hwy 49</title>
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/path/to/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#0072C6" key="theme" />
          <meta name="description" content="personal trainer" />
          <meta name="keywords" content="trainer for Cool Gym." />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        </Head>
        <section className="my-10 mx-5">
          <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row text-center justify-center items-center">
            <div className="relative min-h-screen w-full md:w-2/3 mx-8 mt-16">
              <Image
                src={url}
                alt={`This is an image of ${url}`}
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="cover"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="w-full text-center mt-5">
              <h5 className="mb-2 text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                {name}
              </h5>
              <p className="mb-5 text-base text-left text-gray-500 sm:text-lg dark:text-gray-400">
                {bio}
              </p>
              <p className="mb-5 text-base text-left text-gray-500 sm:text-lg dark:text-gray-400">
                {bio2}
              </p>
              <p className="mb-5 text-base text-left text-gray-500 sm:text-lg dark:text-gray-400">
                {bio3}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

type TrainerPaths = {
  params: TrainerParams;
};

type TrainerParams = {
  trainer: string;
};

const transformQueryResponseToProps = (
  data: AllTrainersQuery
): TrainerProps => {
  const allTrainer: SlugTrainerFragment[] = data?.allTrainer;
  const trainers = allTrainer[0];
  const { bio, bio2, bio3, name, image } = trainers;
  const url = image?.asset?.url;

  return {
    bio,
    bio2,
    bio3,
    name,
    url,
    navigationTree,
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<TrainerParams> = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query<AllTrainersQuery>({
    query: AllTrainersDocument,
  });

  const allTrainer: TrainerFragment[] = data?.allTrainer;

  const paths: TrainerPaths[] = allTrainer.map(({ slug }) => ({
    params: {
      trainer: [slug?.current].join("-"),
    },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<
  TrainerProps,
  TrainerParams
> = async ({ params }) => {
  if (params === undefined) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  const { trainer } = params;
  const { data } = await client.query<TrainerBySlugQuery>({
    query: TrainerBySlugDocument,
    variables: {
      slug: trainer,
    },
  });
  return {
    props: transformQueryResponseToProps(data),
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you wanting to have the navigation tree data coming from sanity instead of from a file in your repo? (If it's always just going to live in the repo then you could just import it directly into your nav component).

Comment: If you're wanting to move that data to sanity then there are probably a few ways you could tackle this. One way would be to query for the data when you query for the rest of the page data in getStaticProps and inject it as a page prop.

However, if you're using graphQL it might be better to look at using some kind of cache that get's serialized and passed up to the client from getStaticProps where it's then rehydrated. Then you could just use graphQL to query for it directly in your nav component, without requiring a network request.

Comment: Hey @madze, I'd like to have the navigation tree data come from Sanity! Thanks for your help and advice!